# Asterisk ARI - ChannelDestroyed event not firing when using early bridging

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I'm using Asterisk 18 with ARI's node library. This specific issue is quite simple: I aim to create a channel, add it to an existing bridge where some participants already are, then dial the channel. This way participants in the bridge can hear the call's early media since ARI will have control of the channel upon creation, as opposed to originate where the channel can only join the bridge after being answered.

However, I noticed very weird behavior when I create a channel and dial it, then the callee rejects the call. Expected behavior: a ChannelDestroyed event fires. Actual behavior: nothing, asterisk CLI shows that it received busy response but the event doesn't fire in ARI. Furthermore, when I try to delete the channel through ARI, it responds with channel not found.

I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution!!!

I used `wscat -c "ws://localhost:8088/ari/events?api_key=asterisk:asterisk&app=hello-world"` to subscribe to show all events as in the ARI documentation on Asterisk's website. Turns out I need to subscribe to `Dial` event, which has a field that shows progress.